SageMaker ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateEndpointConfig operation
It's a lab environment created by aws but I DO NOT have the permission to change IAM role nor Service control policy. The error is reproducible and everytime I could get the same error message. The key IAM service role shows it actually has permissions on creating the SageMaker Endpoint along with the Config.
IAM Permissions (Partial)
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/sagemaker_studio_role",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "IAM1"
        },
        {
            "Action": "iam:ListRoles",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "IAM2"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ecr:*",
                "sagemaker:CreateEndpoint",
                "sagemaker:CreateEndpointConfig",
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Sid": "Sagemaker1"
        }
    ]
}

Scenario (Study Case)

Cloud Quest > Machine Learning > Chatbots with a Large Language Model (LLM)

Steps (Stuck on step 2)

Use Amonzone SageMaker JumpStart to access pretrained models, such as FLAN-T5-XL, for quick ML initiation and NLP tasks.
Deploy ML models by using the Amazon SageMaker real-time inference endpoint.
Integrate AWS Lambda with Amazon Lex, using LangChain to connect with SageMaker.
Implement an Amazon Lex V2 fallback intent to handle unmatched user inputs.

Error Messages (ClientError)

ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the CreateEndpointConfig operation: User: arn:aws:sts::920******910:assumed-role/sagemaker_studio_role/SageMaker is not authorized to perform: sagemaker:CreateEndpointConfig on resource: arn:aws:sagemaker:us-east-1:920******910:endpoint-config/jumpstart-example-huggingface-text2text-2024-09-02-23-45-22-813 with an explicit deny in a service control policy

Sample Code (Jupyter Notebook)
# Deploy the Model. Note that we need to pass Predictor class when we deploy model through the Model class
# defined above, so we can run inference through the sagemaker API.
model_predictor = model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1,
    instance_type='ml.g5.xlarge',
    predictor_cls=sagemaker.predictor.Predictor,
    endpoint_name='jumpstart-example-huggingface-text2text-2024-09-03-03-36-14-616',
)

References

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/security_iam_troubleshoot.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/security_iam_id-based-policy-examples.html


Because you are using a lab environment created by AWS, there are account-level permission restrictions in addition to the IAM level. If you are attending an AWS-hosted lab event, contact the event facilitator. If you are running the lab self-service, make sure you are following the lab instructions only.
